# IN clause on SQL-Column-datatype-XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML text in the column(e.g column name:  xmlColumn in Customer tabel)
I wanted to use IN clause and it should match the value of xpath (Address/street/No/text())

```
Select *  
from tbCustomer  
where xmlColumn (Address/street/No/text()) IN (1, 2, 3)
```

How can I achieve this?

I already tried with following condition and it works fine. But I don't want to use the LIKE operator.

```
WHERE CAST(xmlColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) like (1) OR <br/>
           CAST(xmlColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) like (2)
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will be really helpful.

Comment: Close. `SELECT * FROM tbCustomer WHERE xmlColumn.value('(/Address/street/No/text())[1]', 'INT') IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: How can I include the above where condition in the following LINQ: <br/>  var dataSource = from c in tbCustomer
             join o in tbOrder  on c.custID = o.custid
             select new 
             {  c.custID,
                c.custtname,
                 o.ordername
             }

Comment: You don't. No flavor of LINQ provider I know of can forward XML queries transparently. You would actually have to retrieve the XML column and parse the XML in C# (with XPath if you like) or else expose the column through a view so you can query directly on that.